# httpd redirects with SSL and subdomains/vhosts

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, https

I'm trying to setup http -> https redirected subdomains on my website, which is being served by Apache (Version: 2.2.31). I purchased a wildcard SSL certificate that is installed correctly for my main site (`www.domain.com`) because I get a green lock next to the address, so that part should be done.

**The issue**: browsing to `subdomain.domain.com` redirects to `www.domain.com` and I can't figure out why. I've been reading and following [this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) page as well as several others with similar content, but I'm missing the key ingredient.

The main site is served from `/var/www/html` and the subdomain is served from `/var/www/vhosts/subdomain`. Also, I'm getting this error:

`[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence`

Here's the vhost section of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    #Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com
    Redirect 302 / https://www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com
    #Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.com
    Redirect 302 / https://subdomain.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ...
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile        /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile     /path/to/key
    SSLCertificateChainFile   /path/to/bundle
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/subdomain
    ...
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile        /path/to/cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile     /path/to/key
    SSLCertificateChainFile   /path/to/bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's `apachectl -S` output (with my domain name redacted/substituted):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

=======================================================================

**Edit:** I removed the word permanent, cleared my cache, and the problem persists. It seems like it has to do with the warning, right?

Also, I get a successful response regardless of which `subdomain` I use even when it doesn't exist. I can literally type whatever I want for `subdomain` and it goes to the main site. `http://<anything>.domain.com` and `https://<anything>.domain.com` both load the main site with https.

Comment: show apachectl -S? Maybe some other vhost hiding somewhere.  Or maybe you've over-scrubbed this conf and the name-based vhosts are subtly wrong compared to your input URL.

Comment: @covener added to my OP

Comment: I don't see anything glaringly wrong with the config. You are using permanent redirect though, so perhaps you had the wrong config a while back and your browser is storing the redirect. Have you tried using a different browser?

Comment: @NickBrown I removed the word permanent and cleared my cache, but the problem persists. I think the problem is either with the redirect statement (the slash may need something after it?) or in my ssl.conf file where I'm handling the request. I can't get the warning to go away...

Comment: I added something to my update. Regardless of which `subdomain` I use, the main site loads via https.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu. When adding NameVirtualHost *:443 to /etc/apache2/ports.conf (which is where it was historically), restarting Apache gives me this error:
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/ports.conf:5

All sites which do not have a <VirtualHost *:443> are automatically redirected to the first vhost (alphabetically) with a :443 section.
Defining a :443 section with a redirect to :80 generates a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was simple, but elusive, at least to me. In `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`, I needed to add the following line for the VirtualHost configurations to be distinct:

`NameVirtualHost *:443`

Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you Anthony!